# How to avoid hard coded username/password in jira.cfg for pytest_jira plugin

Tags: python, jira, pytest, python-jira

I am trying to integrate `pytest-jira` plugin to my python script. I am referring to this [link](https://github.com/rhevm-qe-automation/pytest_jira).

It is not feasible to hard code username/password in clear text form in `~/jira.cfg`. Is there any way I can override them from outside? Basically I am looking for ways to skip hard coding of password in `jira.cfg`.

```
username = USERNAME (or blank for no authentication
password = PASSWORD (or blank for no authentication)
```

Can someone suggest a way to do this?

Comment: according to the readme in the pytest-jira repository, you can put `jira.cfg` somewhere else. that doesn't get around the apparent plain-text requirement. You could always engineer some additional solution to get the username and password from an external source and create the `jira.cfg` file dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply overwrite the arguments by defining your own `pytest_configure` hook. That's the beauty of `pytest`: you can redefine almost everything and adapt it to your particular needs. Example with reading username/password from environment variables:

```
# conftest.py

import os
import pytest


def pytest_configure(config):
    username = os.getenv('JIRA_USER', None)
    password = os.getenv('JIRA_PASSWORD', None)
    if username and password:
        config.option.jira_username = username
        config.option.jira_password = password
```

That's it! Test it:

```
$ export JIRA_USER=me JIRA_PASSWORD=mypass
$ pytest --jira
```

Comment: glad I could help!